# streams; comparing objects

Tags: java, sorting, stream, comparator

Hello i got a question about streams.

I wanna sort my list of objects. I wanna compare the Attributes by their names and compare the integer variable number of each object.

Below there is my code. And i commented the line which doesn't work. How can i sort by the variable name of the non primitive attribute Attribute of my Object?

```
List<Object> objects
List<Object> sortedObjects = objects.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object::getAtt().getName)) //this doesn't work.
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object::getNumber))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

public class Object {
    Attribute att;
    int number;
    
    public Attribute getAtt() {
        return att;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}

public class Attribute {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `::` denotes a method reference.  You can only place a single name after it, not code.  As rzwitserloot said, use a lambda if you want code.

Answer (score 2):

> `Object::getAtt().getName`

This isn't a thing. `o -> o.getAtt().getName()` is what you're looking for, I think.